# AWS ALEXA NOT able to see the "Send Alexa Events" Slider

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/authenticate-a-customer-permissions.html IN the above page it is mentioned that

Sign in to the developer console and select the skill.
On the PERMISSIONS page, slide Send Alexa Events to indicate your skill will send asynchronous responses and/or change report events.

I am NOT able to see the "Send Alexa Events" Slider?

Answer (score 0):

I just went to the Alexa developer console at https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask , created a new smarthome skill, then clicked on the permissions tab (left navigation column) from the build section (top navigation row) and there was an on/off slider switch for "send Alexa events."

Since you're calling it "AWS Alexa" maybe you're mistakenly going into the AWS console?

Maybe you created the wrong skill type? If you create a "custom" skill, it won't have the smarthome permissions tab.

Comment: You are correct. If you create a custom skill the smarthome permissions tab is not present. Any workaround to enable send alexa events in custom model?